# racket: detect bitmap label of button (to switch between labels on button click)

Tags: button, bitmap, label, panel, racket

current code:

```
(define test (new button%
   [parent lower_panel]
   [label (make-bitmap-label "" testPic2)]
   [callback (λ (o e)
               (cond
                 ((= label pic) (send test set-label testPic2))
                 ((= label pic) (send test set-label testPic1)) )]
   ))
```

instead of (= label pic) I need some sort of code to get the current label so I can switch it to the alternate one. An example would be perfect, any other comments welcome! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a buttons label using the [`get-label`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/window___.html?q=get-label#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._window~3c~25~3e%29._get-label%29%29) method.

Thus, taking your example (and switching the labels just to be `"label1"` and `"label2"`, we get:

```
#lang racket/gui

(define frame (new frame% [label "Example"]))

(define test (new button%
                  [parent frame]
                  [label "label1"]
                  [callback (λ (o e)
                              (cond
                                [(equal? (send test get-label) "label1")
                                 (send test set-label "label2")]
                                [(equal? (send test get-label) "label2")
                                 (send test set-label "label1")]))]))

(send frame show #t)
```

This creates a window with a single button that alternates between the text `"label1"` and `"label2"` when you press it.

Comment: thank you so much you are my (and my group's) saviour :')